# no registered handler for URL scheme itms-apps - Rate button Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, debugging, rate

I'm making RATE button for iPad Pro. When tapping on Rate Button, the debug area shows...

**LaunchServices: ERROR: There is no registered handler for URL scheme itms-apps**

```
-(IBAction)RateButton:(id)sender{

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id12345678"]];

}
```

Why am I getting a "no registered handler for URL scheme" error when I have a URL present in code?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The URL you're using is correct. BUT if you're trying this on the simulator it won't work and it will show that exact error. The App Store app URL Scheme only works on a device.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot connect to the ios (iPhone operating software) app store if you are on the simulator.  This url wont work because you are not on a ios device. Ios devices only can connect to the ios app store.